# Не работает z-index для :before

Tags: css, z-index

Есть два элемента

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.first {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #0b1531;
  background: #eef6fe;
}

.second {
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #0b1531;
  position: relative;
}
```

У внутреннего элемента с помощью :before добавляется тень
CSS

```
.second:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  top: 56px;
  left: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Если у :before стоит z-index -1, то тень пропадает, если 0 и выше - накладывается на элемент.
Нужно, чтобы тень была видна, но чтобы она была под элементом.
Ссылка на jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/taelshaany/am0wrdgx/

Answer (score 7):

Кому-то может пригодиться решение с 3D:

```css
el {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

el:after {
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле тень у вас располагается как раз под вторым блоком. Но также она располагается и под первым, из-за чего ее не видно.

Решить просто - добавьте стили для первого блока:

```
.first {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Этим вы заставите браузер при отрисовке страницы учитывать первый блок и корректно наложить тень над первым блоком, но под вторым.